# Sample product data and content for sample website

Tags: product

I need to build a sample site for our portal and need some help finding some free product data, content and imagery to download.

Can anyone recommend a good site?

Answer (score 0):

Try the open catalog [Icecat](http://www.icecat.biz/). There is a option for free data access.